# Java - Converting yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ to readable dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: java, date

I will have a String input in the style of:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

Is it possible to convert this String into a date, and after, parsing it into a readable `dd-MM-yyyy` Date Object?

Comment: _Is it possible._ Why not you can. Search it in Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It can be done in two parts as follows:

1. Parse your `String` to `Date` object

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
   Date dt = sd1.parse(myString);
   ```
2. Format the `Date` object to desirable format

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sd2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String newDate = sd2.format(dt);
   System.out.println(newDate);
   ```

You will have to use two different `SimpleDateFormat` since the two date formats are different.

Input:

```
2015-01-12T10:02:00+0530
```

Output:

```
2015-01-12
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Parse the string into a date variable
Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(dateString);

//Now reformat it using desired display pattern:
String displayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(parsedDate);
```